# Ubuntu 20.4 error en el sudo

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

Buenas el dia de ayer 12 de enero de 2022, se salio un error el ubuntu 20.4 tanto en el equipo que lo tengo como servidor como en su clon, y en otro que lo tengo en mi laptop como maquina virtual, no se si salio en otros lugares mas, el error que sales es:

sudo: error en /etc/sudo.conf, línea 0 al cargar el complemento «sudoers_policy»
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so sólo tener permisos de escritura por el propietario

No si le paso a alguien mas intente arreglarlo por que tambien todas mis carpetas aparecieron con candado osea protegidas, tambien las compartidas y hasta se me cambio el ip estatico con el que trabajaba, si alguien tuvo el mismo error o le paso algo parecido vendria bien algo de ayuda, ya que opte por copiar mi sistema y database (tambien me salio error en ello trabajo con postgresql),
y volver a atras con un punton de control.
Tambien menciono que cuando pude restaurar el sudo desde modo seguro por consola, ya no inicia el ubuntu se queda en pantalla negra. Trabajo en windows server con hyper V.

Utilizando el comando "ls -l /etc/sudo.conf", me sale:

ls: no se puede acceder a ' /etc/sudo.conf ' : No existe el archivo o el directorio

Tambien menciono que cuando pude restaurar el sudo desde modo seguro por consola, ya no inicia el ubuntu se queda en pantalla negra. Trabajo en windows server con hyper V.

Ayer a eso de las 10:00 am absolutamente sin tocar nada las carpetas del var, etc, usr aparecieron con un candado.

Considere la posibilidad de una hackeo pero tengo un clone del ubuntu en hyper V, el cual esta como pruebas y esta generalmente apagado lo encendi y me dio el mismo error, tal cual.

Utilizando "ls -la /etc | grep sudo", obtengo como respuesta:

-r-xr-xr-x  1   root    root  sudoers

drwxrwxrwx  2   root    root  sudoers.d

Gracias

Comment: ¿Has tocado el fichero sudoers ultimamente? el error dice que solo puede tener permisos de escritura el propietario.

Comment: Podrías incluir la salida de este comando en la pregunta? `ls -l /etc/sudo.conf`

Comment: Has considerado la posibilidad de que te hackearon ese equipo?

Comment: ¿Podrías hacer un ls -la /etc | grep sudo? Los permisos deberian ser solo de lectura para owner, grupo y otros, osea chmod 444 /etc/sudoers

Answer (score 1):

Los permisos del archivo `/etc/sudo.conf` deben ser bastante restrictivos. Esto es lo que deberías hacer (como `root`, porque creo que sudo no te va a funcionar hasta que lo arregles):

```
chmod 644 /etc/sudo.conf
```